# can't install some plugins with vundle

Tags: plugin-vundle

Here is the vundle part of my vimrc file(I'm omitting the rest to have a minimal q, ask me to put the rest if you think it's needed):

```
set nocompatible              " required                                                                                                                                              
filetype off                  " required                                                                                                                                              

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize                                                                                                                                
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim                                                                                                                                                      
call vundle#begin()                                                                                                                                                                    

" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins                                                                                                                       
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')                                                                                                                                                 

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required                                                                                                                                                   
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'                                                                                                                                                             

" Add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle used Bundle instead of Plugin)                                                                                              
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'                                                                                                                                                  
Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'                                                                                                                                                          
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'                                                                                                                                                        


" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line                                                                                                                          
call vundle#end()            " required                                                                                                                                                
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

But when I run :PluginInstall I only get the first one installed except for the vundle itself.
Here is the output I get:

```
" Installing plugins to /home/aran/.vim/bundle                                                                                                                                          
. Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'                                                                                                                                                             
. Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'                                                                                                                                                          
* Helptags
```

Comment: not enough reputation to add comment so i'll try my best.
can you try 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'` to `Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'` and reinstall VundleVim from:

```
 git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

`'gmarik/Vundle.vim'` is now hosted as `'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'`

(From `Vundle.vim`s [README](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/master/README.md))